# ExtJs 4.2 - How to use sourceConfig to format date?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a property grid and we set the source for this from a controller. There is a date field that needs formatting. I checked the documentation but the example is not so easy to understand.

The grid view just has the grid defined. The controller gets the values from the server and then uses setSource to populate the grid.

I tried this:

```
sourceConfig: {
    installationDate: {
        renderer: Ext.util.Format.date('d.m.Y H:i:s')
    }
}
```

How do I format the date using sourceConfig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a renderer function in your [`sourceConfig`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid-cfg-sourceConfig). You can use the utility function  [`Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.Format-method-dateRenderer) to generate it. To set the format for the corresponding editor, use the date field's [`format`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-cfg-format) config.

```
sourceConfig: {
    'dateAttribute': {
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('Y-m-d'),
            editor: {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                format: 'd.m.Y'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also see this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5u7).

**EDIT:**
As pointed out in the comments below, it is important that the keys of `sourceConfig` match exactly with the keys as used in the actual `source` in order for the configuration to apply correctly.

Comment: I'm setting the source from the controller, so the grid view just has the definition of the grid. The date value too is available from the JSON returned from the server. I don't wan't the field to be editable?

Comment: What stops you from setting the source from the controller? I only used `source` in my fiddle to get some dummy data. Read-only properties are not supported by default, but you can achieve it quite easily with a listener on the [`beforeedit`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.Editing-event-beforeedit) event. And of course in that case you can omit the `editor` configuration. I've updated the fiddle accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to my mistake! I was replacing the keys from the JSON with readable equivalents of them. Meaning stackOverflow would become Stack Overflow. I needed to use the latter value! Solved it! Will you please edit your answer and mention that the source key's text has to be used as is in the sourceConfig?